# pecl install trader failes with missing file - OSX Lion

Tags: php, macos, pear, pecl

I am trying to install the trader pecl extension and I keep getting an error during the make. If anyone could try this and let me know if they get a similar error or if anyone knows a solution.

```
pecl install trader-beta
```

This is part of the output.

```
  creating libtool
  appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
  configure: creating ./config.status
  config.status: creating config.h
  running: make
  /bin/sh /private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootpwFTIe/trader-0.2.1/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/trader -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootpwFTIe/trader-0.2.1/include -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootpwFTIe/trader-0.2.1/main -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/trader -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/trader/ta-lib/include -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/trader/ta-lib/src/ta_common -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/trader/functions  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /private/tmp/pear/temp/trader/ta-lib/src/ta_common/ta_global.c -o ta-lib/src/ta_common/ta_global.lo
  /private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootpwFTIe/trader-0.2.1/libtool: line 1280: ta-lib/src/ta_common/ta_global.loT: No such file or directory
  mkdir ta-lib/src/ta_common/.libs
  mkdir: ta-lib/src/ta_common: No such file or directory
  make: *** [ta-lib/src/ta_common/ta_global.lo] Error 1
  ERROR: `make' failed
  Merges-iMac:etc mike$ which php
  /usr/bin/php
  Merges-iMac:etc mike$ php -version
  PHP 5.3.10 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Feb 20 2012 22:55:53) 
  Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
  Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has something to do with paths not being properly set. I ended up using phpize to compile. I just downloaded the file manually and extracted it.

http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.phpize.php

-happy now

Comment: I have talked with the developer and the latest beta release should now compile properly.